# Haskell home-made monad transformer unable to Show itself in GHCi

Tags: haskell, ghci, monad-transformers, winghci

I am dabbing with simple monad transformers as presented in http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~nhn/MGS2006/LectureNotes/lecture03-9up.pdf

My error-handling transformer has type

```
newtype ET m a = ET (m (Maybe a))
```

I have implemented all the necessary plumbing and I am able to couple it with the identity monad (which in my little sandbox is called `I`) and write/compile non trivial functions.

But I am unable to print any resulting value onscreen. Message is:

```
No instance for (Show (ET I Value)) arising from a use of ‘print’
```

`Maybe` is imported. Both `I` and `Value` derive `Show` and display on their own without problems. It is the mix with `ET` that won't show. I see two ways:

- try to insert `deriving Show` in the declaration of `ET m a` (which I tried in many ways obtaining a lot of different error messages)
- create a showable instance dabbing with "Stand-alone deriving declarations", as suggested by some web resources - tried with no success so far.

How can I show an `ET I Value` in my REPL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the purposes of standalone deriving is that sometimes the compiler cannot infer the required constraint to make a certain instance, even though the actual *code* is still derived mechanically. So you just need to know what constraint to give it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE StandaloneDeriving, UndecidableInstances #-} 

newtype ET m a = ET (m (Maybe a))
deriving instance Show (m (Maybe a)) => Show (ET m a)
```

Comment: Thank you. Perfect. Why in this case there is no indent at the "deriving" line? I'd say it belongs to the newtype declaration. Isn't it so?

Comment: No - standalone deriving introduces new syntax, `deriving instance <class>`, which doesn't need to even be in the same module as the datatype. The two lines are independent declarations.